# Is there a way to read XPR 3d files and convert them to a more common format?

Tags: 3d

I have a project where 3d object information is stored in xpr files.  It is a binary format used in some 3d cad programs.  I would like to be able to read it and transfer it to another format.  c#, c++, and/or vb would all by fine if libraries existed.

My research on the web has indicated that  Adobe Acrobat can import an xpr file, but I really need something like xml that I can read with c#.